# In Ruby on Rails models, why is presence validated on associations but uniqueness validated on foreign keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord, model

I have a model with a foreign key.  Even though there's a database constraint preventing a duplicate `user_id` from entering `SomeClass`'s table, I'm repeating (pre-empting, really) that validation in the model so that it's handled more gracefully.  So my model looks something like this:

```
class SomeClass < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  validates_presence_of :user
  validates_uniqueness_of :user_id
  ...
end
```

It took me a while to realize this is how it needs to be done.  It seems to me that ActiveRecord should expect you to use either `user` or `user_id` consistently on both presence and uniqueness validation.  That would make:

```
validates :user, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true
```

or:

```
validates :user_id, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true
```

possible, which is optimal for code maintainability since it groups all `user` constraints together.  So why instead is it inconsistent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the reason lies in difference between `user_id` and `user`.

Presence of `user` makes sure not only existence of `user_id`, but also presence of the actual user.

As checking uniqueness of user_id and user, AFAIK they may have the same effect, checking of user_id is enough it make sure it is unique.